# Is it possible to install MS Office 2007 Standard English Language Pack on top of Japanese version of Office?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, language

I have a Japanese version of Microsoft Office 2007 Standard, upgraded from Microsoft Office 2003 Standard.

Is it possible to install an English Language Pack or English Language Interface Pack?

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it, but it seems like it's possible.
Here's what says Microsoft's [FAQ for Language Packs for the 2007 Microsoft Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/suites/HA102113691033.aspx) :

> An Office Language Pack enables a user
>   or organization to add localized UI
>   and document proofing tools for an
>   additional language **to their base 2007 Microsoft Office language** deployment
>   and to easily switch between them.

So it looks like you can add languages to any base/starting Office installation.

Office language packs are apparently less limited than Windows language packs. The later can only be added to an English version, but Office is not so limited.